# uploading audio file from mozilla firefox in php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

when I upload an audio file with chrome it uploads fluently without any error but when I am uploading it in firefox it doesn't give me an error but doesn't upload my file either this is my code

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
          $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          if ((
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
            )
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $audio = date('YmdHis') . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "uploads/top_songs/" . $audio);
          }
          else{
            $audio = "";
          }
```

Comment: use the upload library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla Firefox gives `audio/mpeg` MIME type to mp3 files according to the standart [RFC 3003](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003), unlike chrome which gives `audio/mp3`.

The correct solution would be

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$allowedMimes = array("audio/mp3", "audio/wma", "audio/mpeg");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimes) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $audio = date('YmdHis') . '.' . end($temp);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/top_songs/" . $audio);
}else{
    $audio = "";
}
```